# MLT - 10-bit LUT support

Tags: video, colors, mlt

I'm an MLT user via several open source NLE video editors (kdenlive).

It appears that MLT is unable to process a 10 bit LUT.

Prior to MLT 6.10 applying a 10 bit LUT like the DJI Mavic 2 Pro DLOG-M LUT resulted in blank output.  After upgrading to MLT 6.10, the output is non-blank, but the LUT is not actually applied.

Perhaps there's a problem with DJI's LUT, but I suspect it's just a 10-bit vs 8-bit thing.  Can anyone confirm, and weigh in on whether 10-bit support is in the pipeline?  If so, the benefit would accrue to a lot of projects.   I can supply luts and video samples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific about which MLT filter you are using. There are several provided through [FFmpeg libavfilter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lut1d). There is no universal standard LUT file format, and I suppose [lut3d](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-lut3d-1) does not support that LUT format.